# np.zeros((2,1)) vs np.zeros([2,1]) whats difference between them?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Whats the difference between `np.zeros((2,1))` and `np.zeros([2,1])`

All seems true but why the different way to make

```
import numpy as np
np.zeros((2,1)) == np.zeros([2,1])   # return array([[ True], [ True]], dtype=bool)
np.zeros((2,1)).shape               # return (2,1)
np.zeros([2,1]).shape                # return (2,1)
```

Comment: There is no difference.  The docs really should be updated to match other methods that correctly state, "an `int` or sequence of `ints`", rather than "an `int` or tuple of `ints`"

Comment: Often tuples and lists provide the same information.  There are a few contexts in numpy where the difference matters - eg. indexing and defining structured arrays,

Comment: By all practical means there is no difference. The tuple is, however, more natural since the `shape` attribute of a numpy array is a tuple. The tuple version seems marginally faster, perhaps because the tuple is used directly for the shape?

Comment: @PaulPanzer: Numpy reconstructs the tuple every time you ask for `.shape` (it stores an an array of `intptr_t`s in C), so there is no such optimization.

Comment: @user3483203: I think the intent behind the documentation is _"we want to encourage users to use tuples here, but we don't care enough to forbid lists - we just won't tell them explicitly it's allowed"_.

Comment: @Eric ah, that's why! I was doublechecking (after posting the comment) and was puzzled by the shape having a different `id` than the tuple (argument to zeros et al). Because in plain Python it's not trivial to make an actual copy of a tuple. For example, slice copying or `copy.copy`ing return a reference to the same object.

Answer (score -1):

np.zeros((2,1)) parameter passed is tuple(immutable). np.zeros([2,1]) parameter passed is list(mutable).
Hope this helps.